# Manual optimization in the past (C Language)

Tags: c, optimization, history

Back in the 70s when C just started, I guess compiler level optimization wasn't that advanced like modern compilers (clang, gcc, etc...) and the computers themselves were limited hardware-wise, was it common to prefer optimizations at the source code level over readability?

Example:

```
int arrayOfItems[30]; // Global variable

int GetItemAt(int index)
{
    return globalArrayOfThings[index];
}

int main()
{
    // Code
    // ... arrayOfItems intialized somewhere
    // More code

    GetSomethingByItem(GetItemAt(4)); // Get at index 4

    return 0;
}
```

Now this can be optimized to this:

```
int arrayOfItems[30]; // Global variable

int main()
{
    // Code
    // ... arrayOfItems intialized somewhere
    // More code

    GetSomethingByItem(arrayOfItems[4]); // Get at index 4

    return 0;
}
```

Completely omitting the function`GetItemAt` and thus saving time by **accessing the value** straight from it's address instead of entering a function, creating a stack frame, **accessing the value** and pushing the result to some register. Do people used to prefer to write the second, 'optimized' version straight into the source code or use the first version so the code would be more readable?

I know that in this example you can use a processor to "mimic" this optimization (e.g `#define GetItemAt(x) arrayOfItems[x]`), but you get my point.

Also, maybe this exact optimization feature was present from the start, if so, I should find another example, suggestions are welcome.

**TL;DR -**

- Was it common in the past to prefer optimizations at the source code level over readability?

Bonus question:

- Are there optimizations that are included only so the source code can be more readable?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  If it's "At one point did a compiler exist that didn't make this optimisation?", then the answer is "Yes, probably.".

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I edited my question, should be more clear now.

Comment: your question doesn't cut the point enough. i offer another better example: a good efficiency-aware c programmer should write `x/2` as `x >> 1`, both in the old days and now. to be honest, i don't prefer to play with this oo trick when dealing with global variables. it's seriously useless.

Comment: I get the point but the example is rather odd. I think if you care enough to worry about optimization you'd care enough to provide some bound checking in the getter, which would bring in other questions.

Comment: You seem to be lumping an awful lot of things under the heading of "readability", e.g. modularity, ease of code reuse, testability, encapsulation, maintainability, portability, etc. It's always been the case that you optimize when you need to, and when you know you need to, otherwise folks would have just stuck with assembly.

Comment: There certainly were cases where, eg, the stand-alone `x++;` would be preferred over the `++x;` (or maybe vice-versa) because one was faster than the other.  And turning array indexing into pointer indexing was done quite often, for performance.  A C programming class in the 70s might well have included a few hours on this topic.  But bear in mind that, in addition to not having optimizing compilers, the CPUs of that era were about 1000 time slower than modern ones.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about history.

Comment: @Kevin - Those who ignore history are doomed to repeat it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think many developers have ever *prefered* optimization over readability, but sometimes it might be argued that there were optimizations that harmed readability but were necessary for performance. Something like [Duff's Device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) (a loop unrolling optimization)

From

```
do {               /* count > 0 assumed */
  *to = *from++;   /* "to" pointer is NOT incremented, see explanation below */
} while(--count > 0);
```

to

```
register n = (count + 7) / 8;
switch(count % 8) {
case 0: do {    *to = *from++;
case 7:     *to = *from++;
case 6:     *to = *from++;
case 5:     *to = *from++;
case 4:     *to = *from++;
case 3:     *to = *from++;
case 2:     *to = *from++;
case 1:     *to = *from++;
    } while(--n > 0);
}
```

Of course, it turns out that compilers got smarter and it has been reported on the LKML that [removing](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0008.2/0171.html) Duff's Device *improved* performance and *reduced* memory usage. From the linked wikipedia,

> For the purpose of memory-to-memory copies (which was not the original use of Duff's device, although it can be modified to serve this purpose as described in section below), the standard C library provides function `memcpy`; it will not perform worse than a memory-to-memory copy version of this code, and may contain architecture-specific optimizations that will make it significantly faster

and from the LKML (in 2000)

> ... this effect in the X server.
>   It turns out that with branch predictions and the relative speed of CPU
>   vs. memory changing over the past decade, loop unrolling is pretty much
>   pointless. In fact, by eliminating all instances of Duff's Device from
>   the XFree86 4.0 server, the server shrunk in size by ***half a megabyte***, and was faster to boot, because the elimination of all
>   that excess code meant that the X server wasn't thrashing the cache
>   lines as much.

As for optimizations that only improve readability, it would require that your code first be unreadable. Then anything that makes it more readable would seem to qualify. Finally, remember that [premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Comment: Another example of such harming of readability is use of function-like macros instead of ordinary functions. I recall that this was a nightmare do debug these multiline macro-expansions within GNU MP library.